# The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted exception while accessing WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wcf, web-services

I am running a WCF service that is consumed by a Windows Forms client. I am using Windows Authentication on the server and the WCF service is working fine. All the functions implemented in the service are working fine on the client application except one function. I checked the service code for `[DataContract]` and  `[OperationContract]` of that function and even I checked the Svc Log using SvcLogViewer.exe. But the function keeps raising `NullReferenceException`. The exception that I found from SvcLog is

```
The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted
```

This function is working fine on local server but not on remote. What I want to know that is the reasons for this exception to occur and following is my ServiceModel code:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="Wrabind" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" sendTimeout="00:25:00">
          <textMessageEncoding/>
          <security authenticationMode="SecureConversation" includeTimestamp="true" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
            <localClientSettings maxClockSkew="00:30:00" />
            <localServiceSettings maxClockSkew="00:30:00" />
            <secureConversationBootstrap messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
              <localClientSettings maxClockSkew="00:30:00" />
              <localServiceSettings maxClockSkew="00:30:00" />
            </secureConversationBootstrap>
          </security>
          <httpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" allowCookies="true" maxBufferSize="20000000" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WCoreService.Service1Behavior" name="WCoreService.Service1">
        <endpoint address="http://subdomain.domain.com/service1.svc" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="Wrabind" contract="WCoreService.IService1" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WCoreService.Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment>
      <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
        <add prefix="http://subdomain.domain.com/" />
      </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it myself. There was some logical error in the code that I was unable to find but somehow going through the whole control flow I found that little error. The error was actually that on client side I was calling that faulty service function on a place where service connection was not created yet. It was being created later in the code. So I just shifted the connection creation code before that call to the faulty service function and it worked. I hope someone with the same issue may find this solution useful.